Derivation for BNF
Given a grammar for something like: h(x) or function(x)
<Definition> ::= <Name> <LeftPar> <param> <RightPar>
<Name> ::= <Letter><LetterTail> 
<LetterTail> ::= <Letter><LetterTail> | ‘’

When it comes to derivation. Lets say I have func(x)
Definition -> Name LeftPar param RightPar
                -> Letter LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
                -> f LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
                -> f Letter LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
                -> fu LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
                -> fu Letter LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
                -> fun LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
                -> fun Letter LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
                -> func LetterTailLeftPar  param RightPar
                -> func [EMPTY] LeftPar param RightPar
                -> func ( param RightPar
                -> func (x RightPar
                -> func (x)

As you can see only this part is multiple lines which got me wondering if I am doing right. For example do I have to wait that long to say EMPTY for example? I will not write [EMPTY ]in my derivation but just to make it clear in this case. Could I escape that line and move directly?  Say like this? Also does this look like a correct derivation, btw my grammar is bigger and I get full 2 page derivation for a very simple expression. Am I doing something wrong?
-> func LetterTail param RightPar
-> func ( param RightPar

You don't need to write [EMPTY] but you do need to remember that it takes one step to replace LetterTail with the empty sequence.
It's mainly big because you keep copying the rest of the stack at every step. You can align symbols to the right to make the unchanged parts obvious:
Definition ->                  Name LeftPar param RightPar
           ->     Letter LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
           -> f          LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
           -> f   Letter LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
           -> fu         LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
           -> fu  Letter LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
           -> fun        LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
           -> fun Letter LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
           -> func       LetterTail LeftPar param RightPar
           -> func                  LeftPar param RightPar
           -> func (                        param RightPar
           -> func (x                             RightPar
           -> func (x)

and then omit the parts that don't change.
Definition ->                  Name LeftPar param RightPar
           ->     Letter LetterTail ...
           -> f          LetterTail ...
           -> f   Letter LetterTail ...
           -> fu         LetterTail ...
           -> fu  Letter LetterTail ...
           -> fun        LetterTail ...
           -> fun Letter LetterTail ...
           -> func       LetterTail ...
           -> func                  LeftPar ...
           -> func (                        param ...
           -> func (x                             RightPar
           -> func (x)

You can also replace LeftPar and RightPar with terminal symbols in the grammar so you don't need separate steps to replace them.
<Definition> ::= <Name> ( <param> )

Unless you were told to stick to a specific order of expansion, you can expand multiple symbols in parallel.
Definition
Name                                   ( param )
Letter LetterTail                      ( x     )
f      Letter LetterTail               ( x     )
f      u      Letter LetterTail        ( x     )
f      u      n      Letter LetterTail ( x     )
f      u      n      c                 ( x     )

A derivation is really a tree. Nonterminals are nodes. Terminals are leaves. Definition is the root. Every node expands to its children, below itself. The result is basically the "parallel expansion" above with even less repetition.
Definition
Name                                   ( param )
Letter LetterTail                        x
f      Letter LetterTail
       u      Letter LetterTail
              n      Letter LetterTail
                     c

